# How to paste individually in a list if the vectors are different in lengths

Tags: r, paste

I have a question on how to use the `paste` function in a list if its vectors are of different lengths. I have a dataframe with columns of different lengths, such as:

```
df = data.frame(Set1=c("abc",'def',"ghi","jkl",""), Set2=c("abc",'def',"","",""), Set3=c("mno","pqr","stu","vwx","xyz"))
```

I tried to make a list `a.list` based on each column and collapse each factor with a `,`. Something like

```
a.list

$Set1
[1] abc,def,ghi,jkl

$Set2
[1] abc,def

$Set3
[1] mno,pqr,stu,vwx,xyz
```

I tried

```
> a.list = apply(df, 2, as.list)
> a.list = lapply(a.list, function(x) paste(x, collapse=",")
```

However, it collapsed the factors with `,` to the maximum length of the list. For example,

```
a.list

$Set1
[1] "abc,def,ghi,jkl,"

$Set2
[1] "abc,def,,,"
```

Sorry it may be a simple question. I am still learning R. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can remove the `''` with `setdiff` after looping over the columns with `lapply`, then `paste` the rest of the elements (`toString`).  Note that `toString` => `paste(..., collapse=", ")`

```
lapply(df, function(x) toString(setdiff(x, '')))
```

This assumes that there are `unique` elements in the column.  If there are duplicates, use `vsetdiff`

```
library(vecsets)
lapply(df, function(x) toString(vsetdiff(x, '')))
```

Or using `nzchar`

```
lapply(df, function(x) toString(x[nzchar(x)]))
#$Set1
#[1] "abc, def, ghi, jkl"

#$Set2
#[1] "abc, def"

#$Set3
#[1] "mno, pqr, stu, vwx, xyz"
```

Also, it may be better to return a `vector` instead of `list` as each element of the `list` is of `length` 1

```
sapply(df, function(x) toString(x[nzchar(x)]))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ str_c(.[nzchar(.)], collapse=",")))
```

NOTE: We don't need to create a logical vector with `!=` as `nzchar` already does that

Comment: Be aware that `setdiff` removes any duplicate entries and it is not the same as just removing `''` blanks. E.g. `setdiff(c("abc","abc",""), "")` returns `"abc"` once only.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the empty values from each element in the list and `paste` the values.

```
lapply(df, function(x) paste(x[x!=''], collapse = ","))

#$Set1
#[1] "abc,def,ghi,jkl"

#$Set2
#[1] "abc,def"

#$Set3
#[1] "mno,pqr,stu,vwx,xyz"
```